# Storage mechanism for a Google Doc like real-time editor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dom, real-time, wysiwyg

I have put together a text editor (WYSIWYG) and I am able to send deltas back and forth in structures like these:

```
{
    "action": "insert",
    "position": 25,
    "content": "some text"
}
```

and I have implemented a way to send these to all participating clients and to apply the delta at the destination.

**ISSUE**

### Storage

I am now trying to figure out how to handle the storage mechanism on the server side. I use `MongoDB` as a primary database and since these deltas come though so often, I imagine that writing all of them into the database as they come could stress the database out very quickly.

*possible solution*

I am considering assembling the document in memory and flushing the document back to the database say every 10 seconds (but what if I lose changes before writing them to database? Also, memory is very precious)

### Serving

Say I have successfully stored `100 000` of these changes together forming one document, is it wise to pull all of them and render them onto the editor when someone loads the document (manipulating the DOM seems resource intensive), or is it better to apply them to the document as soon as they reach the server and return them already assembled when the document is requested?

With the proposed solution above, I would just be getting a document instead of an array of deltas to process. But I wanted to stay away from sending HTML content to the client.

How do services like Google Docs handle this? Any advice on implementation is welcome.

Thanks

---

**Resources so far:**

- [Process of applying changes concurrently](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ykZYKCK7AM&hd=1)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how Google Docs does it, but this sort of thing is what DBs like Redis and Memcached are designed for.  They are primarily in-memory, but have a regular flush to disk to persist.  There's not perfect atomicity, but generally you're not going to have both perfect transactional integrity and perfect scalability in the same solution; it's usually some kind of tradeoff involved.